# Pass argument of type required by method using universal function pointer C++

Tags: c++, pointers, arguments

I am trying to figure out how to use a pointer to the function, in which I would be able to pass an argument of type which is required by this function?

Example:In one place I use handler() pointer to point testInt() function and I want to pass int value there. In other place I wan to reuse handler() to point testFloat() with float value.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void testInt(int a){
    printf("Int\n");
}

void testFloat(float a){
    printf("Float\n");
}

int main() {
    void (*handler)(void);

    handler = &testFloat;
    handler(5.5);

    handler = &testInt;
    handler(3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: do you really think this has anything to do with the c language? Please dont spam tags

Comment: @tobi303, ignoring the "using namespace std" makes it pure C. Don't be to harsh.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie except in C it'd throw up a load of errors as neither function matches the type of `handler`

Comment: Defining it as `void (*handler)(void *prm);` can do the trick and then call it with `handler(&myFloat);` or `handler(&myInt);`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie and the `<iostream>` and the fact that c++ has completely different ways of dealing with function pointers than c.

Comment: @ChrisTurner, but that is exactly his question, isn't it?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie question title says C++

Comment: @ChrisTurner, user squeamish ossifrage edited the tags to remove C. I think he rather could have removed the c++ tag. I added the tag again.

Comment: Sorry for this "C" tag, probably I chose it from the suggested tags list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both function have a different arguments you need some kind of adapter which will be able to perform conversion from `int` -> `float` or vice versa.
Note compiler is unable to deduce which conversion is proper so it can't provide it out of the box.

One way to fix it:

```
void testInt(int a){
    printf("Int %d\n", a);
}

void testFloat(float a){
    printf("Float %f\n", a);
}

void testIntAdaptor(float a){
    testInt(static_cast<int>(a));
}

int main() {
    void (*handler)(float);

    handler = &testFloat;
    handler(5.5);

    handler = &testIntAdaptor;
    handler(3);

    return 0;
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/OF3UqpQmuiyTnfrO

More modern way to do it:

```
void testInt(int a){
    printf("Int %d\n", a);
}

void testFloat(float a){
    printf("Float %f\n", a);
}

int main() {
    std::function<void(float)> handler;

    handler = &testFloat;
    handler(5.5);

    handler = [](float x) { testInt(static_cast<int>(x)); };
    handler(3);

    return 0;
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/UpnJRRrE0sqgBWue

Or [mixed version](https://wandbox.org/permlink/msEKzq8K6sBSe8TG)